# Medrash Tanchumah 0n Teshuvah

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, sin, repentance-teshuvah

I read a book which quoted the Medrash Tanchumah ([Parshas Vayeira 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Vayera.18/he/Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet?lang=bi))
as stating the following:

*"Teshuvah so powerful that it eradicates one’s sins so that no blemishes remain on his soul."*

I looked it up the medrash and could not find this quote.

Does anyone know where I can find this quote?

Comment: Which book was it?

Comment: Regarding the topic at hand, note the Talmudic dictum that a baal teshuv is greater than one who did not sin. That would seem to be everything in this Tanhuma, and more.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya truth seeker. If you happen to be the same user as chiddushei-torah, note that these sort of questions, lacking the relevant information, are what led to the account suspension. || If not, welcome again. Note that it is important to  always include all relevant information in a post, as this can help others answer it. For example, in this case, telling us which book it is,  could be helpful. Thanks. Hopefully you will choose to stick around the site and contribute in a productive way. || Including the cited source for the Tanhuma, as you did, is certainly helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The quote is probably the following (Tanhuma Vayeira 16 in ed. Buber):

> ראה מה יפה התשובה, אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא שובו אלי ואשובה אליכם (מלאכי ג
>   ז), שאם ביד אדם כמה עונות והוא שב לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא, הוא מעלה עליו
>   כאילו לא חטא
>
> See how good repentance is, God said: "return to me and I will return
>   to you", that if a person has several sins in his hand, but he repents
>   before God, He considers it as though he did not sin.